configure attribute field to a dropdown list with POSTGIS
I know that for a vector layer in qgis, I can go to its properties and set one of its field to be "Unique Values" or "Value Map", so that whenever I add new features in, I can select from predefined list of values.
But how to set this up when this layer is actually a postgis database layer, and every time I add it from database, this configuration is automatically set up? What do I need to set up from the database side?
thanks

figured it out, for those who are interested: set the target column to be enum in postgres will do the trick.
